# ListView Resizing crash with Custom Trigger and FluidMoveBehavior

Tags: wpf, triggers, behavior, blend

I m using FluidMoveBehavior from Blend in my WPF project, the FluidMoveBehavior is animating the child items of a ListView that I have in a usercontrol.
Additionally I also have a MultiTrigger that animate the each item within the ListView when MouseOver event.

This is causing random crashes when I resize the MainWindow and if the Mouse Overs some listview Item while the FluidMoveBehavior is animating the items inside the wrap panel.

To overcome this problem I though that I should create a simple bool Dp (e.g. AnimationAllowedProperty) for the UserControl that I could use to block the MouseOver animation in the ListView/Items when the windows is resizing or when the FluidMoveBehavior is animating the ListView Items. 
With this new Dp (e.g. AnimationAllowedProperty) I could validate its value (true/false) in my Trigger to block or allow the custom trigger animation.

So my question is what event should I use in My UserControl or ListView or other to detect when the control is resizing or when FluidMoveBehavior is animating or other, and when if finished Resizing so I can set this custom Dp to true or false.

Any other suggestions or alternatives are welcome
Thank you.